# Where to keep active user data on React + Redux client application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

On my React + Redux client app, I need to get the active user info (fetch from myapp.com/users/me) and keep it somewhere so that I can access it from multiple components.

I guess `window.activeUser = data` would not be the best practice. But I could not find any resource about the best practice of doing that. What would be the best way to do what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can keep it in a separate reducer, and then import multiple parts of your state with `connect()` in your components.

Say if you have 2 reducers called `users.js` and `tags.js` which are combined with `combineReducers` when setting up your store. You would simply pull different parts by passing a function to your `connect()` call. So using es6 + decorators:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {users: state.users, tags: state.tags}
}

@connect(mapStateToProps)
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
```

and then down in your `render` function:

```
return (
  <div>
    <p>{this.props.users.activeUsernameOrWhatever}</p>
    <p>{this.props.tags.activeTags.join('|')}</p>
  </div>
);
```

So your different reducer states become objects on `this.props`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use React's [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), HOC or global variables to make your data available to multiple components, via context

Something like...

```
class ParentDataComponent extends React.Component {
   // make data accessible for children
  getChildContext() {
    return { 
      data: "your-fetchet-data"  
    };
  }

  render() {
    return < Child />
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // access data from Parent's context
    return (<div> {this.context.data} </div>); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create an action creator and call it on `componentWillMount` of the appropriate component so it runs right before your component mounts, and in the action creator fetch the data you need and pass it to a reducer. in that reducer you can keep the data you want throughout your application. so whenever you needed the data you can retrieve it from redux state. [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) tutorial from official redux website covers everything you need to know. mention me if you had any questions.